# reformat a GPT external HDD to MBR/exFAT

Tags: macos, partition, external-disk, disk-format, exfat

I am currently looking for a solution (if it exists) to change my external 4 TB SATA HD from a GUID Partition Table to an MBR with an exFAT volume.

I did not see an already answered solution but if there is one please let me know!

I thought I would be using the HD for my mac 10.9.5. However, I have boatloads of data on other hard drives and have decided maybe I want to use this disk as a master boot disk for my PS4. I tried reformatting the whole disk in Disk Utility but the Master Boot Record option is not available. The current status of the HD is as follows:

[image: HD Description]

When I attempt to re-partition the HD, I followed the partition process, and all seems well, until I end up at this screen:

[image: Problem Area]

Is there a way to completely erase the partition table/reformat to exFAT?
(save the cash)

Or is my best bet to invest in another external HDD?
(lose the cash)

Comment: Yes. I erased all Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volumes in untitled 1. Also in the 4 TB ASMT 2105 Media External. Receiving the same error on the partition options page.

Comment: [2TiB limit MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)

Comment: @klanomath so does that mean I am only able to use a 2 terrabyte external HD with an exFAT partition set as an MBR?

Comment: On a 4 TB disk configuring two partition may work. The second partition has to start **before** the 2 TiB-limit

Comment: @klanomath attempted to add pictures of the partitions however I don't have enough rep to do so. The journaled partition (partition 1) is less than 200GB and the ExFat partition (partition 2) is 3.69TB. Still will not allow me to choose the Master Boot Record option on the ExFAT partition.

Comment: 3.69 TB is way beyond the 2 TiB. It's more less a double 2 TiB limit: no partition larger than 2 TiB allowed and the second partition has to start before the 2 TiB limit. So min size of the 1st partition is ~1.802 and the max size is ~2.198 TB on a 4 TB disk.

Comment: @klanomath ahhh I see. Still receiving the same result with partition 1 (ExFAT) at 1.88 TB (above min and below max) and the rest as "Free Space" or any other format. Should I be ignoring any options within the Erase or RAID sections of the Disk Utility? Thanks so much for your continuing assistance.

Comment: I don't know if this works at all in macOS. It used to work as a work-around in Windows

Comment: @klanomath thanks for the help! If you do end up finding the solution in the future I would really appreciate it. I'm noticing that macOS is a little more difficult to find answers for regarding software/hardware. Windows seems to have a lot more work arounds.